# Generating 10 byte octet number from Integer in Java

Tags: java

I need to generate a 10 bytes number in the below format in Java

```
00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:00:88:99
```

- 1st byte - should be always 0
- next 4 bytes - Should be derived from integer (will be passed as input to the method)
- next 5 bytes - Can be a number

Don't understand how to achieve it in java. Any example or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: give more examples on what you tried? how are bytes eventually being populated, we are not magicians here

Comment: @Vihar _Are we not?_ Programming sometimes feels like magic. (black magic)

Comment: @ParkerHalo definitely yes, but only when we know what magic we need to perform

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve the solution create a Regular Expression for the given string and this code shall be able to give you your desired result.

```
 public static final String regex="";

  public static String getString() {

    String randString = generateRandomString();


    while (!randString.matches(regex)) {
            randString = generateRandomString();    }

    return randomPassword;
} 

  private static String generateRandomString() {

    final String chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:";
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuffer passwordString = new StringBuffer();

    int passwordLength = random.nextInt(4) + 8; // Password length is 8 to
                                                // 11 chars.

    for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {

        passwordString.append(chars.charAt(random.nextInt(chars.length())));
    }

    return passwordString.toString();
}
```

Just Place the Regex in the String "regex" .

Comment: Is this a contest for the least efficient implementation possible?

Comment: @aaron Can you Come Up with an Efficient Solution ?

Comment: I believe I could, but there are a few problems with the question. 1) the last part of the desired result ("could be a number") is badly defined : any byte could be a number. Are four more zeroes okay? If not, why? Should they be random? 2) I've no idea where OP is stuck, which makes it very hard to deliver an appropriate answer. Should I explain how `for` loop work? Maybe how bytes cast to integers? What `String.join` does? There's too much to explain if we assume he knows nothing, and if I just produce code he'll copy-paste without understanding I've just defeated the purpose of the homework

Comment: But if you're curious I'd start with a `List<Integer>` I would populate with the desired numbers, I would map it with `Integer.toHexString(int i)` to a `List<String>`, which I could then `String.join` to obtain the desired result.